# How to deploy a jbpm project having more than one ProcessDefinition.xml file?

Tags: java, deployment, jbpm

I want to know what jbpm internally do to deploy the processdefinition.xml, so I can use the same strategy to put more than one process definitions in a project.

Please give the internal working of deployment, and also the classes that play role in deploying the process.

One more thing that I want to add is that, I am working in jBPM 3.2.2 version. So, if possible give answer specific to the version or provide the jBPM version also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have worked on 3.2.7. I would suggest to go with the latest 6.X which have drools engine integrated.

regarding the deployment you need to remeber that the child needs to be deployed before the parent.

Ex. A(parent)--refer--> B(child/subprocess)  then B should be deployed before A.

So when A is deployed it will get the B's reference.

If you are not sure about all the relation then another way is to deploy all the process 2 times so that it will automatically find the references.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out after having a thorough research, that the following classes play a crucial role in deployment of processDefinitions.
These classes are JbpmConfiguration, JbpmContext, ProcessDefinition.
By studying these classes one can understand the deployment method.

But, for internal working I am still trying to figure it out.